# Conversão de Farenheit para Centígrados sempre dá zero

Tags: c, tipagem

Este é o exercício:

> 1.12.3. A conversão de graus Farenheit para centígrados é obtida por
>   5
>   C = 9(F - 32)
>   Fazer um algoritmo que calcule e escreva uma tabela de centígrados em função de graus Farenheit, que variam de 50 a 150 de 1 em 1.

Fiz meu código assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    float F, C;

    for (F=50; F<=150; F++) {
        printf("--------------------------------\n");
        printf("Farenheit = %.0f",F);
        C = (5 / 9) * (F - 32);
        printf("\nConvertido para centígrados = %.2f\n",C);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Eu fiz alguma coisa errada no código ou é erro do compilador?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro "nunca" é do compilador, é sempre do programador.

O problema é que está misturando números com ponto flutuante e inteiro. Quanto dá 5 divido por 9? Dá 0, aí multiplicar por qualquer coisa dá 0.

Aproveitei para simplificar um pouco:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    for (float F = 50; F <= 150; F++) {
        printf("--------------------------------\n");
        printf("Farenheit = %.0f\nConvertido para centígrados = %.2f\n", F, (5.0f / 9.0f) * (F - 32.0f));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/P7W8GR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pudlrsiu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/IntXFloat.c).

Comment: O GCC não reconhece esta sintaxe `for (float F = 50 ...)` :(

Comment: @gato Só se for um GCC bem velho. Mesmo assim use `-std=c99`. É um completo absurdo continuar usando C da década de 80 que usa uma prática considerada ruim nos dias de hoje.

Comment: A minha versão é `gcc (tdm-2) 4.8.1` qual versão eu posso usar? O `-std=c99` é uma flag? Teria como habilitar no code-blocks esta opção?

Comment: Ah, tem essas distribuições diferentes. É uma *flag*, tem como mexer na linha de comando sim, deve ser isso: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33208733/221800

Comment: Criei uma flag nova `-std=gnu99` em **Build options > Others options** e funcionou aqui :D

Comment: ou, só declare a variável F no começo da função, comos e fez por mais de 40 anos.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar os números com virgula 0.0

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
        // F : Farenheit
        // C : Centígrado   
    double F, C;    
    for (F=50; F<=150; F++) {
        printf("--------------------------------\n");
        printf("Farenheit = %.0f",F);
        C = (5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32.0);
        printf("\nGrau centígrados = %.2f\n",C);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```